# Aws X-ray daemon monitor throws invalid segment Errorcode

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I am trying to run this demo sample by AWS :-
https://github.com/awslabs/lambda-refarch-mapreduce

When run the program on my local then I am receiving this message on my AWS X-RAY daemon monitor

2018-06-28T16:39:06+05:30 [Error] Unprocessed segment: {
  ErrorCode: "InvalidSegment",
  Id: "20bc7ab3728074c9",
  Message: ""
}

So far searched for this problem but could not find much article or anything on internet. Not sure if I am doing something wrong. I have followed exactly the same instructions as mentioned in the sample.

regards,
Bhaskar

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue and it was due to the fact that I used parentheses in the name of the segment I defined.

According to the [X-Ray docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-api-segmentdocuments.html#api-segmentdocuments-fields):

> name – The logical name of the service that handled the request, up to 200 characters. For example, your application's name or domain name. Names can contain Unicode letters, numbers, and whitespace, and the following symbols: _, ., :, /, %, &, #, =, +, , -, @

Answer (score 0):

This forum post might have some useful information regarding what you saw: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=262253&tstart=25. If you go to AWS X-Ray console and check how many subsegments each trace contain and the duration of the trace, that will give you some basic idea of how many subsegments within a single trace the sample sent per second. Then we can take a deeper look if there is any other issue.